# Github Actions CI pipeline that triggers ONLY when merge is successful

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm looking on a way to trigger a GitHub pipeline ONLY on successful pull request merge.

I have to move from Azure DevOps where I had some arguments like these:

```
condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
```

But I can't seem to find a way to do something similar on GitHub

EDIT:

So

```
on:


pull_request:
    types: [closed]

jobs:
  on-success:
    if: ${{ github.event.pull_request.merged }}
    steps:
      - name: my-step
        run: echo "Hello World!"
```

Works but only on manually accepted PRs, which is not what I need.

The answers should work with git CLI if you do:

```
git checkout main
git merge dev
```

and then accept the changes and commit+push

Then the actions should be triggered and these last answers doesn't work with that.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you cannot do this.

When you're running `git merge` you're just merging branches in git, you're not merging a Pull Request in GitHub. Git is the underlying version control system used by GitHub, but git itself has no concept of pull requests.

If you want to trigger a GitHub action, you need to generate an event on the GitHub pull request, therefore you need to use github's own CLI, not git CLI. See `gh pr merge` https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_merge

Answer (score 0):

You can use `push` trigger. Please refer to https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#push

On the branch that the Pull request will be merged, you can add the condition and it will get triggered.

Ex:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'main'
      - 'releases/**'
```

Comment: but this will make it that it also get triggered if its not a merge right ?

Comment: @DavidMuñozTord Yes, but you could enable branch protection to require PRs.

Comment: Yes, but that's not what is asked.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-workflow-when-a-pull-request-merges-1

```yaml
on:
  pull_request_target:
    types:
      - closed

jobs:
  if_merged:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - run: |
        echo The PR was merged
```

Comment: Doesn't work with git cli unfortunately.

Comment: Your original question was about something else then - "pull request merge".
This is different from 'on branch merge'.

Comment: @DavidMuñozTord Edited my answer. Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The try using this to double check for sucess.

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [closed]
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  on-success:
    if: ${{ github.event.pull_request.conclusion == 'success'}}
    steps:
```

Comment: Same as above, doesn't work with git cli unfortunately.